# What type to use for reusable html element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a hook that returns ref for html element:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>();
```

In my main file I want to change the src at some point and do:

```
imageRef.current.src = nextSrc;
```

I get typescript error saying that `src` doesn't exist. I want my hook to be able to return refs for different html elements, not only images, but I still tried extending type by:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLElement | HTMLImageElement>();
```

But I still got error:

```
Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement | HTMLImageElement'.
```

Is there any way I can fix it and keep my hook reusable for different html elements?

Comment: if you care only about `src: string` why not `useRef<{src: string}>`?

Comment: that's only this case, I want hook to be reusable, so I don't want to constraint it. It would be nice if I could either specify all supported types or have `HTMLElement` and specify on creation of `imageRef` that it is actually `HTMLImageElement`